# Legal / latin term for argument that treats someone else's injuries as one's own?

Tags: legal-terms, from-the-latin

Interning in a court, and I note that the defendant's brief once had a case dismissed because of potential overreach by the court, but that overreach would not injure the defendant's interests, it would injure others.

I feel like there's a legal or latin term for this kind of argumentation -- where you're acting as if injuries to someone else are actually injuries to you, and requesting relief for those injuries.

Does such a term exist, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [third-party standing](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/article-3/section-2/clause-1/standing-to-assert-the-rights-of-others).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from bdb484's answer:

[***jus terti***](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/jus_terti) is the...

> latin term meaning third-party standing.